# grails validation using regex

Tags: regex, validation, grails

Hi i am trying to validate a Date for  mm/dd/yyyy patterns using regex in command object constraints.

regex:

```
^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$
```

grails constraints

```
static constraints = {
        date(blank:false)
        date(matches:"^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$")
}
```

i am getting following error

```
unexpected char: '\' @ line 61, column 47.
^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])
```

it is not accepting the \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape "\" and "$" signs:

```
"^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))\$"
```